# Filter a query using the CONCAT function or similar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is filtered on a list of order numbers.  The actual filed for the order number is 9 characters long (char).  However, occasionally the system that the end users get their order numbers from will generate an extra 0 or single alpha character to the beginning of this order number.  I am trying to account for that using the existing SQL and although it is running, it takes exponentially longer (and sometimes won't even run).

Is the approach I am taking below the best way to account for these differences?

order number field example:

066005485,
066005612

example of what may be entered and I need to account for:

0066005485,
A066005612

Here is what I have tried that seems to not work or at least be EXTREMELY slow:

```
SELECT S.order_no AS 'contract_no',
       S.SIZE_INDEX AS 'technical_index',
       S.open_qty AS 'contract_open_qty',
       S.order_qty AS 'contract_order_qty',
       E.excess,
       (S.order_qty - E.excess) AS 'new_contract_size_qty'

FROM   EXCESS E 
JOIN   SIM S ON RIGHT(E.GPS_CONTRACT_NUMBER,9) = S.order_no AND E.[AFS TECH INDEX] = S.size_index

WHERE S.order_no IN ('0066003816','0066003817','0066005485','0066005612','0066005390','0066005616','0066005617','A066005969','A066005970','0066005952','0066005798','0066006673','0066005802','0066006196','0066006197','0066006199','0066006205','0066006697')

OR   CONCAT('0',S.order_no) IN ('0066003816','0066003817','0066005485','0066005612','0066005390','0066005616','0066005617','A066005969','A066005970','0066005952','0066005798','0066006673','0066005802','0066006196','0066006197','0066006199','0066006205','0066006697')

ORDER BY S.order_no, 
         S.size_index
```

Any thoughts on something that may work better or I am missing?

Comment: You want to avoid transforming your column data at all costs, because as soon as you do that SQL Server is unable to make use of indexes. Instead you need to transform your incoming criteria.

Comment: Your `ON` clause is also non-SARGable, due to the `RIGHT`. The fact that you need to use it implies your column is being used to contain multiple data items in a single value.

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They only work when you define them, no where else; `ORDER BY 'value'` would *not* order by your column aliased as `'value'`, it would order by the `varchar` literal `'value'` (so would effectively not order at all). Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Using functions such as `right()` and `concat()` in your join and where conditions is forcing SQL Server to scan all rows in the table/index every time. Imagine 100 boxes in a row, each with a number on the outside, and I asked you to find the boxes with the number 10 on it - easy. Now do that if the number is inside the closed box, you must open each box in turn and look - that's what your functions are forcing SQL Server to do.

Comment: As noted above, it will likely be more efficient to remove the first character of the input rather than `concat`ing it to the column. e.g. `WHERE order_no IN ('0066003816', '066003816')` covers the two cases and can use an index on order_no.

Comment: @Blazer1984 no I am saying that instead of transforming your column to match the input with the extra zero (if I understand correctly), perform your second test against the input having removed one zero (or whatever it is they are getting wrong).

Answer (score 1):

I can't do anything about the nasty join that requires the right function.  If you have any influence over the data base designers it could be fruitful to either have that key (E.GPS_CONTRACT_NUMBER) cleaned up before it is put into the table or get them to add another field where the RIGHT(E.GPS_CONTRACT_NUMBER,9) has already been performed and an index can be created.

But there is definitely something you can do to remove the concat function calculation and take advantage of any index on S.order_no.  I noticed your Where clause looks like *order_no IN listofvals OR Concat('0', order_no) IN samelistofvals* .  So instead of **adding** a zero onto order_no **remove** a zero from everything in the IN list.

```
Where order_no IN ('0066003816','0066003817','0066005485','0066005612','0066005390','0066005616','0066005617','A066005969','A066005970','0066005952','0066005798','0066006673','0066005802','0066006196','0066006197','0066006199','0066006205','0066006697', 
'066003816','066003817','066005485','066005612','066005390','066005616','066005617','066005952','066005798','066006673','066005802','066006196','066006197','066006199','066006205','066006697')
```

Notice that the IN-list is on two lines and the second line is just the first repeated with the leading 0 removed and any entry beginning with "A" removed entirely.  This simplifies the Where clause and allows use of indexes, if any exist.

Answer (score 0):

If the efficiency problem is in the `WHERE` clause (not considering the `JOIN` operation), in order to improve the situation, you can try using the "pseudo-regex" pattern matching way with `LIKE`:

```
WHERE 
    S.order_no LIKE '[A0]06600%' 
OR 
    S.order_no LIKE '06600%'
```

Warning: this pattern will match also strings that end with other numbers (e.g. 8648).

Does it work for you?